# Unwanted run through else/if not loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, file, if-statement

This is a small but crucial error because it affects the code where you have to give a specific 'not found message'....but the problem might also lie with the fact that i'm using csv files.
In this code I specified that 'not found' must be printed only if the record is not found, but it keeps printing anyways.

CODE

```
import csv
with open('data.csv','w') as f:
    ans='y'
    while ans=='y':
        s=csv.writer(f)
        g=int(input("Enter GR number:"))
        n=input("Enter name:")
        m=float(input("Enter total marks:"))
        s.writerow([g,n,m])
        print()
        ans=input('Enter more?')
        
with open('data.csv','r') as f:
    print("SEARCHING FOR GR NUMBER")
    print()
    gr=int(input('Enter GR number to search:'))
    s=list(csv.reader(f))
    for i in s:
        if str(gr) in i:
            print(i)
    if str(gr) not in i:
        print('Record not found')
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter GR number:234
Enter name:Mia
Enter total marks:80

Enter more?y
Enter GR number:456
Enter name:Mark
Enter total marks:80

Enter more?n
SEARCHING FOR GR NUMBER

Enter GR number to search:234
['234', 'Mia', '80.0']
Record not found
```

I have even tried other methods to print not found...but the same error occurs anyways lol. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's because after your `for` loop finds the record, it searches to the end anyway and, when it's finished, hits the check for record found. What do you suppose the value of `i` is when your `for` loop completes?

Comment: 'i' 'is the record in list form....but the second if is outside the for loop itself

Comment: I understand that :) I'm explaining why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you might also want to print multiple records with the same `GR` number, try this:

```
found = False
for i in s:
    if str(gr) in i:
        print(i)
        found = True
if not found:
    print('Record not found')
```

In your code, you'd only check the *last* line that was iterated :)

Answer (score 2):

This particular case calls for Python's seemingly strange `for ... else`-construct. The `else`-branch is only chosen if the `for`-loop does not end because of a `break`-statement.

Try this:

```
for i in csv.reader(f):
    if str(gr) in i:
        print(i)
        break
else:
    print('Record not found')
```

Comment: ohh Thankyou so much the code works beautifully plus it makes sense....but of course now 2 records or more cannot be printed though its ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are writing the last block a little wrong.

```
if str(gr) not in i:
        print('Record not found')
```

The above code as written by you is simply checking if the `str(gr)` is not present in i and which will be write for any of the iteration as i think it will be only present at a particular position. Thus printing **not found**.

Here is a solution;

```
def check():
    for i in s:
        if str(gr) in i:
            print(i)
            return
    print('Record not found')

check()
```

Here i am just checking the same condition but if matched, i am just getting out of the function, thus not printing the last line (i.e, **not found**). And if it doesn't satisfy the if condition, it will move to last line.

Comment: Thankyou so much....now the first part works beautifully....but when i enter a grno which is not in the record...it prints 'record not found' four times

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario element `i` is an iterator of container `s`. Since you are using a Python list the items will be ordered by insertion,. So `i == 234` on the first iteration and `i == 456` on the second iteration. Next, you check `if "234" not in "456":` which is true.

Comment: but even if i use else statement within the for loop it still gives the same error

Comment: Instead of `if str(gr) not in i` which is checking that state of an iterator from a exited loop (probably not something that you want to be doing), you could instead do `if str(gr) not in s` which will print the error only when a user hasn't entered the matching GR number.

Comment: Note that the suggestion in my comment above should solve you problem with minimal changes, but it is not a optimal approach since it iterates the list twice. A more solution might be using a boolean (e.g., `found = True`) to indicate when at least one record is found. You can then print the error `if not found`.

Comment: @Durtal provided a great [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838062/6762624). I didn't event know there was a for/else construct in Python. It eliminates the need to manage a `found` boolean while accomplishing the same behavior.